# Excel 2003 - filter by multiple items

Tags: excel

How do I turn a pull down filter menu with check boxes, where you can select multiple filters?

I higher versions when I expand the filter I can see all values in filtered columns and tick/untick those that want/do not want to see. Is there such an option in 2003?

Answer (score 0):

Might be overkill, but you should be able to do what you want with a pivot table. (I don't think it's possible to do *exactly* what you want in Excel 2003, no.)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, responding to my question. I can be done with Advanced filter - criteria range. I have to create a table with the same column and in the table I put my criteria.

What I do not like about it is that changing values in criteria table does not affect the filter and I have to reapply it again.